# Utilizando Login do Facebook no Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone, login

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Windows Phone 8.1 e nela é necessário utilizar o login do Facebook. Alguém teria um exemplo de como fazer esse login?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Para chamares app do facebook podes fazer assim:

```
string url = string.Format("fbconnect://authorize?client_id={0}&scope={1}&redirect_uri=msft-{2}:authorizeByFacebook", ConfigConstants.FacebookAppID(), ConfigConstants.FacebookPermitions(), ConfigConstants.AppID().Replace("-", ""));
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(url));
```

Depois no Manifest (Onde diz prod_id mete o teu ProductID sem os "-")

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="msft-PROD_ID" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

Quando a app voltar a iniciar podes ver os protocolos e dai tiras o token do facebook!

Espero que ajude